# How to optimize the number of observers in Observables function?

Tags: angular, observable, observers

```
return new Observable(observer => {
  this.isLocationEnabled()
      .subscribe(
        isEnabled => {
          if(isEnabled) {
            observer.next(true);
          } else {
            this.resolveRequestLocationEnable() //notice this duplicate method
                .subscribe(
                  success => observer.next(success),
                  error => observer.error(error)
                );
          }
        },
        error => {
          this.resolveRequestLocationEnable() //notice this duplicate method
              .subscribe(
                success => observer.next(success),
                error => observer.error(error)
              );
        }
      );
}).first();
```

This is an example of a big function which returns an Observable and uses observers for transfer the errors/next to the consumer

Do you see any way of improving this? Using any other observable method or pattern

Answer (score 0):

Nested subscribe blocks are an anti pattern. It can be much simpler then that. Try this:

```
 import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
 import { catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

 this.isLocationEnabled().pipe(
  catchError(() => of(true)),
  mergeMap(isEnabled => isEnabled 
    ? of(true) 
    : this.resolveRequestLocationEnable()
);
```

The `catchError` operator ignores errors from `isLocationEnabled` stream, and proceeds to the `resolveRequestLocationEnable()` call, since you want to call that method in case of both, error and success.

Next if `isEnabled` is true we return immediately with `of(true)`. If it's false we return the result from `resolveRequestLocationEnable()`.